# ImageMagick identify reports incorrect GIF frame count

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, gif, node-imagemagick, imagemagick-identify

I'm using ImageMagick to do some stuff with GIF images.

One of my steps is `identify`ing the number of frames in an image.
I'm calling `identify` via [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick/) (and later [gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm)) like this:

```
identify -format '%T,%w,%h ' test.gif
```

Most of the time I correctly get 53 space-separated values for 53 frames.
But **sometimes I get 47 or 50 frames for the same GIF image** (that has 53 frames).

How can this possibly happen?

I'm running `convert -coalesce -append test.gif other.gif` at the same time, but it shouldn't touch the original image, right? Moreover I checked and the original image is just fine, even when wrong number of frames is reported.

I can't even reproduce this consistently. Where do I look for the problem?

This seems to happen when I'm running several ImageMagick processes concurrently (on different files).

I'm using ImageMagick 6.8.7-9 Q16 x86_64 2013-12-11.

The image in question:

[image]

(But I've had this happen to other images.)

Comment: Can you put up a link to your image?

Comment: @dlemstra: Sure, just added it. However I've had this issue with another image as well.

Comment: Add a `%s` to the format string to get the frame number ("scene").  Perhaps you can identify if a frame is being dropped during the decode, dropped from the front, or dropped at the end.  Using `-verbose` also dumps a whole lot of information, including a "X of Y" string for each frame.

Comment: @Charles: You beat me to it! Stay tuned, I'm posting an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was not an ImageMagick problem at all.
My code for downloading the image to the server was faulty, always skipping some last fifty bytes or so.

This was too easy to miss because it didn't impact GIF's quality severely.